# Fastest algorithm for extracting 25% and 75% marks

Tags: algorithm

I'm hand rolling some visualization algorithms.

Extracting the min/max of a time series is $O(n)$, for n entries.

If I want the 25% and 75% mark, I could use an $O(n \log n)$ time sort, then get the 25% and 75% marks.

However, is there a way to do this in linear time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to find kth largest element in an unsorted list in linear time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on). However, depending on what program you are using, implementing the algorithm might not increase performance. The built-in `sort` function is probably optimized in C, and hence is very fast.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot the genius that is Tarjan.